# Программирование Си. Проверка бита

Tags: c

Часто встречаю следующий код.

```
if (x & (1<<n)) {
  n-th bit is set
} else {
  n-th bit is not set
}
```

Но ведь это не правда?

```
x = 16
1<<5 == 32

16 ==  0b10000
&        |||||
32 == 0b100000
         00000
```

По идее нужна предыдущая степень двойки?

Comment: Возможно, подразумевается, что счёт идёт не с единицы, а с нуля?

Comment: @andreymal Не понял. Можете развернуть?

Comment: n=0 первый (младший) бит, n=1 второй бит и так далее

Comment: @andreymal Выше привёл кусок кода и значения битов. Можете указать где находится бит ( n[0] )?

Comment: Из вашего же разъяснения следует, что n=4

Comment: @andreymal Нужно держать в голове что ( n-ый ) бит на самом деле ( n-1 ). Но пишут именно так ( n-th ) поэтому не корректно и вводит в заблуждение. Спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: В `C` принята нумерация с нуля. Самый первый элемент массива - нулевой. Аналогично и биты нумеруются от нуля до 31(63). Но есть одно исключение: строки в исходном коде нумеруются с первой строки, не с нулевой. Никак не могу привыкнуть. :)

Comment: Биты читаются не слева направо а справа налево.Это означает , что первый бит находится в правой части , а не в левой.